# Access match table headers with import sheet columns

Tags: vba, ms-access

new to Access here so hoping someone could help me with this... I'm trying to import .CSV file to DB which works fine and all. The problem is that .CSV file will have various columns and might not be in the same sequence as set in DB tables. It looks like access is importing all columns in a row regardless of the column name.

Using this Do.Cmd below:

```
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "pimmig2", strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
```

For example, table headers in Access:

```
Action, Type, Retek Hierarchy, ID, Name
```

.CSV file headers:

```
Action, Type, Banner, From Banner, Retek Hierarchy, Master Catalogue, ID
```

So what happens is that after the import, column 'From Banner' ends up in 'Retek Hierarchy' and all data in the table is scewd up...

I have set primary keys and all, have SPECS done so run out of options... :( help please...

Comment: I haven't worked with specification files, but I wonder if the problem is there. Also, if you're not getting any joy this way, maybe look into attaching the CSV as a table (or importing to a new table) then running a select insert query.

Comment: yes it does retrieve them in the right order if I'm importing csv to a new table. However, my tables are sitting on ODBC connection so not sure how importing new table locally would work. Unless there is a way to import table locally and then move fields to existing table via ODBC connection... but that's beyond my knowalge ...

Answer (score 1):

A really easy way to deal with this?

Import into a temp table. So, you empty the table, (or drop it). Now import into this table.

You then fire up the query builder, and create a append query. The beauty of this approach is that not only can you setup field to field mapping, but you can EVEN do this if the field names are not exact matches. Once you create this append query with all of the field mapping?

Save that query.

So, now your steps are:
Import data to that table
Execute the append query.

And you can even add formatting, or cast of data types in that append query. So, you can map fields, and do so without having to write/type the fields in code.

So, you still have a wee bit of code, but the key concept of that append query will thus give you the ability to map columns from the import to the production table, and even give you the chance to map fields that don't even have the exact same name.

Thus, in theory, you can choose nice column names for your production data, and the import can have any field names you want. The append query can be created 100% with the query builder, and the welcome ability to choose which columns go to what production columns is all done by choosing the field mapping with combo boxes in the query builder.

The other nice ability of that temp table? Well, you can run some update query, or even some VBA looping code to clean up, or massage the data before you run that one append query to send data into the final production table. So, you not only get field mapping (wthout having to write code), but you also get a chance to clean up, or even remove bad rows of data before you send (append) the imported data to the actual production table.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same issue I had. I used the logic described by Albert above. So moved into a temp table and then inserted certain columns into the table connected via ODBC connection:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database

' Re-link the CSV Table
Set db = CurrentDb
On Error Resume Next:   db.TableDefs.Delete "tblImport":   On Error GoTo 0
db.TableDefs.Refresh
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblImport", _
    FileName:="C:\MyData.csv", HasFieldNames:=true
db.TableDefs.Refresh

' Perform the import
db.Execute "INSERT INTO someTable SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM tblImport " _
   & "WHERE NOT F1 IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')"
db.Close:   Set db = Nothing
```

Since my .CSV file had spaces in the name, had to put them in brackets like that: `[First Name]`